# UIDatePicker does not pop up

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield, uidatepicker

In my app, when the user clicks the UITextField, the UIDatePicker should pop up. However, it is not popping up.When I run it, it just shows 'select the date!' on an action sheet and nothing else.

This is my code from my ViewController.m;

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

-(void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
 {
 [pd resignFirstResponder]; //the textField that you will set the selected date
datePicker = [[UIDatePicker alloc] init]; //declared uidatepicker component

pickerViewDate = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"Select the date!"
                                             delegate:self
                                    cancelButtonTitle:nil
                               destructiveButtonTitle:nil
                                    otherButtonTitles:nil];

datePicker = [[UIDatePicker alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 210, 320, 216)];
datePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeDate; //set your specific mode
datePicker.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setFormatterBehavior:NSDateFormatterBehavior10_4];
[dateFormatter setLocale:[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US"]]; //or another LocaleIdentifier instead of en_US
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd.MM.yyyy"]; //desired format

[datePicker addTarget:self action:@selector(dateChanged) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged]; //the function would be fired when user change the date in datePicker

//now preparing the toolbar which will be displayed at the top of the datePicker
pickerToolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 44)];
pickerToolbar.barStyle=UIBarStyleDefault;
[pickerToolbar sizeToFit];
NSMutableArray *barItems = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
//UIBarButtonItem *flexSpace = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone target:self action:@selector(doneButtonClicked)]; //barbutton item is "DONE" and doneButtonClicked action will be fired when user clicks the button.
//[barItems addObject:flexSpace]; // set the left of the bar

[pickerToolbar setItems:barItems animated:YES];
[pickerViewDate addSubview:pickerToolbar];
[pickerViewDate addSubview:datePicker];
[pickerViewDate showInView:self.view];
[pickerViewDate setBounds:CGRectMake(0,0,320, 464)]; //you can change the position
}

 -(IBAction)dateChanged{

NSDateFormatter *FormatDate = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[FormatDate setLocale: [[NSLocale alloc]
                        initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US"]];
[FormatDate setDateFormat:@"dd.MM.yyyy"];
pd.text = [FormatDate stringFromDate:[datePicker date]];
}

-(BOOL)closeDatePicker:(id)sender{
[pickerViewDate dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:YES];
[pd resignFirstResponder];
return YES;
}

-(IBAction)doneButtonClicked{
[self closeDatePicker:self];
}

 - (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

Please I just need help with knowing what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Why are you using an action sheet for this? Just make the picker view the text field's inputView.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to show `UIActionSheet` at the end of `-(void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField`:

```
-(void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
     {
     [pd resignFirstResponder]; //the textField that you will set the selected date
    datePicker = [[UIDatePicker alloc] init]; //declared uidatepicker component

    pickerViewDate = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"Select the date!"
                                                 delegate:self
                                        cancelButtonTitle:nil
                                   destructiveButtonTitle:nil
                                        otherButtonTitles:nil];

    datePicker = [[UIDatePicker alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 210, 320, 216)];
    datePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeDate; //set your specific mode
    datePicker.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setFormatterBehavior:NSDateFormatterBehavior10_4];
    [dateFormatter setLocale:[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US"]]; //or another LocaleIdentifier instead of en_US
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd.MM.yyyy"]; //desired format

    [datePicker addTarget:self action:@selector(dateChanged) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged]; //the function would be fired when user change the date in datePicker

    //now preparing the toolbar which will be displayed at the top of the datePicker
    pickerToolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 44)];
    pickerToolbar.barStyle=UIBarStyleDefault;
    [pickerToolbar sizeToFit];
    NSMutableArray *barItems = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    //UIBarButtonItem *flexSpace = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone target:self action:@selector(doneButtonClicked)]; //barbutton item is "DONE" and doneButtonClicked action will be fired when user clicks the button.
    //[barItems addObject:flexSpace]; // set the left of the bar

    [pickerToolbar setItems:barItems animated:YES];
    [pickerViewDate addSubview:pickerToolbar];
    [pickerViewDate addSubview:datePicker];
    [pickerViewDate showInView:self.view];
    [pickerViewDate setBounds:CGRectMake(0,0,320, 464)]; //you can change the position
    [pickerViewDate showInView:self.view]; // <---- here, maybe you forgot

}
```

Comment: sorry Im still new at this. Where do i put that line of code?

Answer (score 0):

Read the description of `UIActionSheet` in the Xcode docs. It says:

> UIActionSheet is not designed to be subclassed, **nor should you add
>   views to its hierarchy.**

That last bit is important. You can't add a picker view to an action sheet because you're not supposed to add **any** views to an action sheet.

BTW, `UIActionSheet` is was in iOS 8, and we are about to move to iOS 9, so it will have been deprecated for 2 major releases as of this week. Thus you should not be doing new development with it. I suggest you create your own view controller and present it modally rather than trying to use `UIActionSheet`.

Comment: so I create a viewController that only shows the DatePicker?

Comment: if that's what you want, yes. You probably want OK and cancel buttons on it.